# Subcategory of left-right projective bimodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, representation-theory, functors

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a fixed field. Take a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-algebra $A$ and look at the category $\text{mod}(A^e)$ of finite-dimensional $A$-bimodules. It has a full subcategory $\text{lrp}(A^e)$ that has a objects those $A$-bimodules which are projective when considered as left and as right $A$-modules.

Is that subcategory a dense (or even [absolutely dense](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/absolutely+dense+functor), or [colimit-dense](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.10649.pdf)) subcategory of $\text{mod}(A^e)$?
Is it in some other sense a 'generating subcategory' of $\text{mod}(A^e)$?

In [Left-right projective bimodules and stable equivalences of Morita type](https://www.impan.pl/shop/publication/transaction/download/product/87293) it is claimed that if $A$ is a self-injective algebra, then, 'except for trivial cases', the complement $\text{mod}(A^e)\setminus\text{lrp}(A^e)$ has infinitely many pairwise non-isomorphic indecomposable objects. Don't know if that helps.

Comment: $\text{lrp}(A^e)$ contains the finitely generated projective bimodules. Isn't that enough to prove that it's dense in $\text{mod}(A^e)$? I'm not sure about "absolutely dense".

Comment: @JeremyRickard Sorry, but why is that enough? Just to be sure: To me a dense subcategory $D\subseteq C$ is one where the restricted Yoneda embedding $C\rightarrow [D^{\text{op}},\text{Set}]$ is fully faithful.

Comment: I’ll think it through carefully and write a full answer (if it stands up) when I have some time. But meanwhile, it’s certainly true for the weaker condition of “colimit-dense” (every object of the category is a colimit of a diagram in the subcategory), since every finitely generated bimodule is the cokernel of a map between finitely generated projective bimodules, and hence a coequalizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the subcategory $\operatorname{lpr}(A^{e})$ is dense in
$\operatorname{mod}(A^{e})$.

The following lemma is an immediate consequence of Theorem 5.13 in

*Kelly, G. M.*, [The basic concepts of enriched category theory](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10.pdf), Reprints in Theory and Applications of Categories, No. 10 (2005).

**Lemma.** If $\mathcal{E}\subset\mathcal{D}\subset\mathcal{C}$ are full
inclusions of categories, and $\mathcal{E}$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}$, then
$\mathcal{D}$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}$, and $\mathcal{E}$ is dense in
$\mathcal{D}$. $\square$

Since $A^{e}\oplus A^{e}$ is an object of $\operatorname{lrp}(A^{e})$, to prove
that $\operatorname{lrp}(A^{e})$ is dense in $\operatorname{mod}(A^{e})$ it is
sufficient, by the Lemma, to prove that the full subcategory containing the
single object $A^{e}\oplus A^{e}$ is dense in $\operatorname{mod}(A^{e})$.

But more generally, for any ring $R$, the single object $R\oplus R$ is dense in
the module category of $R$. See, for example, (2.2) in

*Isbell, J. R.*, [Adequate subcategories](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-4/issue-4/Adequate-subcategories/10.1215/ijm/1255456274.full), Ill. J. Math. 4, 541-552 (1960).

(Note that Isbell uses the term "left adequate" instead of "dense".)